# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID - not producing numerical value

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I'm trying to get the last inserted id from my DB to use in another query, but... when I check if it's a numerical value, it fails!

```
// my big insert query goes here //

Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
member_id = rs(0)
rs.Close : Set rs = Nothing

If member_id <> "" AND IsNumeric(member_id) Then
    conn.Execute(" INSERT INTO members_reputation (member_id, awarded_for, awarded_when, awarded_what) " _
    & "VALUES ("&member_id&", 'Created an account', Now(), 1); ")
Else
    Response.Write member_id //testing
    Response.End // testing
End If
```

As you can see, if the IsNumeric condition fails, I'm writing the member_id to the screen (for testing only) which successfully shows the correct ID, but apparently, it's not numerical, so the next query doesn't fire!

Why is this? What is the best solution around it?

**UPDATE**

Okay, I fixed this by using TRIM(), like this:

```
If Trim(member_id) <> "" AND IsNumeric(Trim(member_id)) Then
```

Which makes me happy because it works but makes me sad knowing that such a simple process to get a numerical ID fails. How can asking SQL for an integer ID, produce a whitespace? There is obviously no whitespace in the DB field, neither is there a whitespace in my code. I would still like an answer on this if anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your insert succeeds?

Comment: @MichaelMior: yes, as i say, when i print the id to screen the correct value appears, its just not numerical

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Missed that one.

Comment: @MichaelMior: that's okay buddy.

Comment: What connector are you using? The ODBC Connector?

Comment: @MyOtherMe: I'm using **MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver** connector

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id is to get the ID generated in the last query. As for your case, there is no query before the mysql_insert_id. You could execute to return a MAX(member_id) instead.

Comment: Ah, there is an insert query just before. I didn't put it in because it was soooooo big. I should put this in my question, sorry.

Comment: Is the member_id an auto-increment field?

Comment: could u try cast the value into int?`SELECT CAST(LAST_INSERT_ID() AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);` and see what is the result.

Comment: I actually got round this issue by using TRIM() on the IF statement. Check updated question. I'm still baffled as to why an integer ID is returned from the DB with a whitespace in it. The said DB field or my code definitely has no whitespace. If you can see why, I would love to know. I appreciate your time also.

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is a white-space in the record? I have tried this in an example and there is no white-space. The record type is long, but isnumeric returns false anyway. isobject() returns true. I think your solution is working because trim implicitly casts the objects value to a string, and then isnumeric can correctly interpret the value as a numeric.